# Vb.net delete excel rows by index

Tags: vb.net, excel

I'm trying to delete rows by index using this code:

```
Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Try
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(TempRefPath)
    xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets("w1")

    Dim empty As Integer
    For empty = i + 2 To 2000
        xlWorkSheet.DeleteRow
    Next
    xlWorkBook.Save()
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox2(ex.Message, Me.Page)
Finally
    If Not IsNothing(xlWorkBook) Then
        xlWorkBook.Close()
    End If
    xlApp.Quit()
End Try
```

but the function delete is not found.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no `DeleteRow` and if there were how would it know what row to delete? You can do this without a loop, to delete rows 5=>10:

```
xlWorkSheet.Rows(5 & ":" & 10).Delete()
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Dim xlRange1 As Excel.Range = Nothing
xlRange1 = CType(xlWorkSheet.Rows(RowIndex), Excel.Range)
xlRange1.Delete()
```

from [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3a26c77c-1857-4106-b1a4-ca78db4e1211/how-to-delete-specific-rows-from-excel-worksheet-using-vbnet?forum=vbgeneral).

Comment: Please don't link to external sources. You need to include a complete solution in your answer and only link if you need to add citations. Stack Overflow needs to stand-alone given the external link may become dead in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that the following also works really well!

```
xlC1Sheet.Rows("10:19").delete()
```

Where xlC1Sheet is the sheet you're currently using.

This will delete all rows from row 10, up to and including row 19